# DocuSign - The "Custom Document Fields" are not being returned by the "ListDocuments" API of the "EnvelopesApi" provided by the C# SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, field, docusignapi, document

1. Currently we are having an use-case in which a few **custom data** needs to be **stored** for each **document** of an **DocuSign Envelope**.
2. We are using the `DocumentFields` property of the `Document` class for the same while creating the `EnvelopeDefinition` instance being sent to the `CreateEnvelope` API provided by the **DocuSign C# SDK** as below.

   ```
        var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition {
           Documents = new List<Document> {
               new Document {
                   DocumentFields = new List<NameValue> {
                       new NameValue {
                           Name = "CustomField",
                           Value = "123"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       };
   ```
3. But these **fields** are **not** being **returned** by the `ListDocuments` API though there is a `DocumentFields` property in the `EnvelopeDocument` model class being returned.
   [image: DocuSign_EnvelopeApi_ListDocuments_Response]
4. The same fields are being returned by the `ListDocumentFields` API.
   [image: DocuSign_EnvelopeApi_ListDocumentFields_Response]

Could anyone please let me know if **this** is the **expected behavior** or is there **anyway** these **fields** can be **retrieved** using the `ListDocuments` API to avoid the additional API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior of the DocuSign platform.  The `ListDocuments` API is used to list the high-level meta data around each document in the envelope - for example the document's `name` and `documentId`.  For the more detailed information such as custom field values etc you need to call the `ListDocumentFields` API.